What exactly is the meaning of the term 'the elect'?
The word 'elect' causes a lot of controversy but it is only a word. What is the origin of the word in the original manuscripts and does the word in context mean those who believe "in Christ" or those who were rigidly chosen by God to "have to" believe in Christ?
Colossians 3:12

Put on therefore, as the elect of God, holy and beloved, bowels of mercies, kindness, humbleness of mind, meekness, longsuffering;


"causes a lot of controversy"-Care to explain what controversy you mean and how it relates to your question.

It seems to me that the question is blaming the Apostle Paul for causing 'controversy' by the choice of his word. There is certainly a difference between some who freely state that they have chosen Christ, themselves ; and those who freely confess that they are incapable of making, or maintaining, such an act of will and who say that they have been chosen by the initiative of the Father, who begets them The cause of a 'controversy' lies deeper than Paul's choice of a Greek noun.

@NihilSineDeo I'm confused why you put your answer in comments.

This contains two separate questions. The first, "What exactly is the meaning of the term 'the elect'?" is suitable for this site. The second asks a question of doctrinal interpretation (predestined salvation), which I would say is not suitable for this site. I'd suggest removing the second question from here and asking on Christianity.SE how specific denominations interpret the word.

Another source to research is this book from author Robert Shank on this very subject with great detail and excellent scholarship - https://www.amazon.com/Elect-Son-Robert-Shank-ebook/dp/B004MDL8XY

Concerning ἐκλεκτός, (ἐκλεκτοὶ is the plural form), we can look at the Strong’s Greek 1588 eklektos. The derived English word is “eclectic.” SG 1588 reads

Definition: select, by implication favorite
Usage: chosen out, elect, choice, select, sometimes as subst: of those chosen out by God for the rendering of special service to Him
(of the Hebrew race, particular Hebrews, the Messiah, and the
Christians).

The authoritative, primary scholarly source is called the BDAG (A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature). Here we read the following definitions along with references that define the “semantic range” of the word meaning in Greek.

Pertinent to being selected, chosen [including Colossians 3:12]

Pertinent to being especially distinguished [including 1 Timothy 5:21]

Pertinent to being considered the best in the course of selection [including 1 Peter 2:4,6]


Next, it’s important to consider the context and trajectory of this section of Paul’s letter, and then the usage of the term in the rest of the Bible.
Colossians 3 simple outline
a.  Died and raised with Christ, determine to set your mind on Christ
b.  Determine to put to death earthly values, prejudices, and behaviors
c.  You are eklektoi, set apart, and beloved of God, therefore
d.  Determine to be compassionate, kind, humble, gentle, patient, forgiving, and above all, loving
There seems to be both grace and volition in this outline.
Other Instances of eklektoi
In response to a man thrown out of a wedding due to a lack of wedding clothes:

For many are called, but few are eklectoi.” – Matthew 22:14 ESV

In relation to the ten kings, which are the 10 horns of the seven-headed beast:

They will make war on the Lamb, and the Lamb will conquer them, for he
is Lord of lords and King of kings, and those with him are called and
eklectoi and faithful. – Revelation 17:14 ESV

Notice there are three elements in this last series: "called, chosen, and faithful."
Related instances of eklekton

Greet Rufus, eklekton in the Lord; also his mother, who has been a
mother to me as well. – Romans 16:13 ESV


In the presence of God and of Christ Jesus and of the eklekton
angels I charge you to keep these rules without prejudging, doing
nothing from partiality. – 1 Timothy 5:21 ESV


For it stands in Scripture: “Behold, I am laying in Zion a stone, a
cornerstone [i.e. Jesus] eklekton and precious, and whoever believes
in him will not be put to shame.” – 1 Peter 2:6 ESV

Also note the difference in the use of a similar word, SG1589 eklogé, which BDAG defines as “a special choice, selection.”
Thus, my “chosen” purpose in this answer is not to “build a case” either for or against John Calvin’s interpretation/extrapolation, but rather to understand the original meaning in context with the gospel, letter, or prophecy, and in the broader context of all the scriptures.
It’s become apparent to me that in the process of building a case, one has to exaggerate the importance of some statements in scripture, while deprecating or ignoring the rest. This is not what I want to do.

thank you for your answer which I appreciate ..

thank you for your answer .. I appreciate it .

You're most welcome, Mark!

The English word 'elect' is used in translations older than the more modern ones that say 'chosen'. Such modern ones are the New American Standard Bible, The New International Version, the New Living Translation (and many others.) They all say 'chosen'.
In manuscripts that give rise to 'elect', the Hebrew word is bachir, meaning 'chosen, choice'. As one example, see Isaiah 42:1 - "Behold, my servant, whom I uphold; mine elect, in whom my soul delighteth; I have put my spirit upon him" etc.
In Greek (as in the text in question) the word is eklektos which means 'laid out, chosen, choice'. A good example of the meaning is shown in Romans 9:11:

"...for though the twins were not yet born, and had not done anything
good or bad, in order that God's purpose according to His choice might
stand, not because of works, but because of him who calls..." NASB

In older translations, such as the A.V., the word 'election' is used, and not 'choice', but it is too obvious for words that the two words are synonymous.
God calls those whom he has chosen to be among the great number of 'the elect'. Paul (and other N.T. writers) used the Greek word eklektos which is rightly translated as 'elect', and equally rightly translated as 'chosen'. There is no controversy with the Greek word and its meaning whatsoever. To be one of God's elect is to be one of God's called and chosen ones.

The Hermeneutic aspect of this Q has been answered by me. But, as Ray Butterworth correctly points out in his comment to the OP, the second bit can only be asked on the Christianity site, so if this Q is not to degenerate into arguments, that second bit should be removed by the OP.

It's very simple and understandable.
And you put it very well. There are two corresponding Greek words for this subject.

ἐκλέγω (eklégho, verb) = to speak out (from my mouth) speech, to utter speech
ἐπιλέγω (epelégho, verb) = to address a speech to someone or to repeat something or to answer something

by extension meanings
(when there is someone chosen, there are automatically those who are not useful, i.e. of poor quality)
ἐκλεκτός (eklektós, adjective) < ἐκ + λέγω
The preposition "ἐκ" or "ἐξ" (which is transformed when it follows a vowel in the next word), here has the meaning of "out". Therefore, e.g. when a king wants to marry and wants to choose one woman out of ten women to make her his wife, he goes to these ten women, looks at them, and after deciding, says to the one he likes: hey! You, come out of there, I tell you, I'll make you my wife!
ἐπίλεκτος (epélektos, adjective) < επί + λέγω
The preposition "επί" here means, since it is the adjective in the passive form, as a job has been imposed on it, it has the sense of "upon". E.g. The captain of the special forces army comes to the squad, and reports and says: so-and-so, so-and-so, so-and-so, you have been selected for an underwater invasion for the coast of so-and-so's country!
Conclusion: it is one thing to have been chosen for a work to which one has been assigned to complete, and another to have been chosen for a union with someone (see LXX Genesis chap. 6:2 the verb ἐξελέξαντο [3rd person plural aorist] < ἐκλέγω). In general the verb “ἐκλέγω” has the sense of taking for myself.
I think, the word “elect” is the equivalent word of “ἐκλεκτός”, but you can also say it with chosen.

PHILO De gigantibus 1:64

But if the God of the world, being the only God, is also by especial favor the peculiar God of this individual man, then of necessity the man must also be a man of God; for the name Abraham, being interpreted, signifies, "the elect father of sound," the reason of the good man: for he is chosen out of all, and purified, and the father of the voice by which we speak; and being such a character as this, he is assigned to the one only God, whose minister he becomes, and so makes the path of his whole life straight, using in real truth the royal road, the road of the only king who governs all things, turning aside and deviating neither to the left hand nor to the right.

Philo's commentary in De gigantibus 1:64 provides profound insight into the term "the elect" through the lens of Abraham's character and his unique relationship with God. According to Philo, the term encompasses the following dimensions:

Divine Selection: Philo emphasizes that being "elect" means being specially chosen by God, as Abraham is described as "the elect father of sound." This indicates a deliberate and unique divine favor, marking the individual as distinct and set apart for a purpose aligned with God's will.

Purification and Virtue: The elect person, like Abraham, is "purified," suggesting a moral and spiritual refinement. This purification process prepares the individual for their role as a representative of divine principles.

Father of Sound Reason and Speech: Philo interprets Abraham's name to mean "the elect father of sound," which he associates with the reasoning faculty and the ability to articulate wisdom. This aligns with the idea that the elect are entrusted with embodying and communicating divine wisdom.

Minister of God: Abraham's election leads him to become God's minister, serving as an intermediary who lives in accordance with divine guidance. This implies that the elect are not chosen for privilege alone but for service and obedience to God's will.

Straight Path: Philo highlights that Abraham's life reflects walking the "royal road" of righteousness, avoiding deviation to the left or right. This metaphor illustrates the steadfastness and fidelity required of the elect in their commitment to God's laws and purposes.


Thus, in Philo's understanding, "the elect" are individuals uniquely chosen by God for their virtuous character, their capacity for wisdom and truth, and their unwavering commitment to walking in God's ways. The term signifies not only privilege but also responsibility and moral integrity.
